# Wait until all threads are waiting before first notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

In `MyClass` I create several threads in a loop like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable(lock));
    threads[i].start();
}
```

where `lock` is a property of `MyClass`, and each of these threads, in their `run` method, calls `lock.wait()`.

After I've created these threads I want to assign one of them control of the lock. I tried simply putting `lock.notify()` after the loop, but this runs too  soon - although it's after the loop, none of the threads have yet executed `lock.wait()`, so they all miss the `lock.notify()`, and then wait indefinitely for another one that never comes.

I can halt execution of the main thread for a bit, e.g. execute `Thread.sleep(1000)` before I call `lock.notify()`. This works as it gives the threads a chance to get to the `wait`ing stage before `notify`ing them. But this doesn't seem very elegant, and obviously I'd rather not halt the main execution of my program like this.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: plz provide the source code of your class with the (synchronized methods, waits , notify) else why cant help you

Comment: `wait()` and `notify()` are low-level, primitive methods that are meant to be used in a very specific way.  Read the [Guarded Blocks Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) to learn more.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some more high-level constructs from the concurrency package, such as a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

So you'd set up the Semaphore with a single "permit" before your loop, pass it to your threads, and then all of them would try to "acquire" that permit (which only one of them can do, the others will fail at that).

Even Semaphore is kind of low-level, usually you can find something even more tailored to your actual application, such as blocking queues or concurrent collections.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at `Thread.join()` method which can help you to make wait current thread, until thread which invoked this method is not completed.

Example:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread();
Thread t2 = new Thread();
t1.start();
t1.join();
t2.start();
```

Here `t2` will wait for the completion of `t1`. More about it, you can read [here](https://www.journaldev.com/1024/java-thread-join-example).